# How do I correctly insert ImagePicker to image in header? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am super new at programming and SwiftUI so I will really appreciate your help.

I place a camera icon on my header to open up an action sheet that will let users select camera or photo gallery.

After that I used a VStack to combine all the elements together. The problem now is that when ImagePicker loads, it only shows half of the screen. I suspect it's because of the Vstack. Any idea how I can solve this issue and make the image picker load the whole screen? Thanks guys.

```
struct FeedView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {

        Header()

        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            PostView()
            PostView()


        }
    }

  }
}


struct Header: View {

// For Camera Actionsheet
@State var showActionView: Bool = false
@State var isShown: Bool = false

            HStack {

            // Camera
            CameraButtonView(showActionSheet: $showActionView)

            Spacer()

            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 30)

            }.actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionView, content: { () -> ActionSheet in
                ActionSheet(
                    title: Text("Select image"), message: Text("Please select an image from the photo gallery or use your camera"), buttons: [

                        ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Camera"), action: {

                        }),

                        ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Photo Gallery"), action: {
                            self.isShown.toggle()
                        }),

                        ActionSheet.Button.cancel()

                ])
            })
            if isShown {

            ImagePicker()

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably present your ImagePicker inside a sheet like so:

```swift
HStack {
 // your code
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isShown) {
    ImagePicker()
}
```